How to pass custom config (key/value) pair to android app installed via Microsoft Intune MDM / MAM
I am struggling to understand how I can add custom config to my app on android so that when users download the app from intune, the config automatically is passed with the installation.
The config is a key/value pair:
qrCode: "{"applicationName":"LoremIpsum","baseUrl":"https://LoremIpsum.com.au/01/api/mobile/"}"
acceptTermsAndConditions: true
The qrCode value is a string
The acceptTermsAndConditions value is a boolean
I have managed to get this working with ios very easily. Ios app config provides a nice UI to add key/value pair (first image). Android (second image) however does not provide this UI to add config and I dont understand why. Appreciate if someone can tell me how to get android config to be entered like ios that would be amazing.



After a good week of researching and reading docs, I realised that android is a bit tricky when it comes to passing config.
In order to be able to pass configuration settings via android, one needs to make their android app MAM aware. I.e the app needs to be supported by Intune. There are two ways to do this. You can either add the intune SDK to your app or use the intune app wrapping tool. In my view the app wrapping tool was a bit easier and didnt require and further code to the project.
Intune Wrapping Tool for Android
Once the apk is wrapped, you can then upload the app as a private app on managed google play. Then when you go to apps -> app configuration policies -> create policy -> select app. The UI finally gives me an option to add configuration settings

